# Function does not work when column starts with na values

Tags: r

I have this column in my dataframe that looks like this:

```
dput(data$parameter7)
c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
29L, 28L, 28L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 27L, 27L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 26L, 27L, 29L,..
```

and because the parameter begins with NA values, the function (below) does not work correctly on it. The other parameters do not start with NA values (even though they contain NA values), and the function works perfectly with those parameters.
Any recommendations on how to handle the NA values so that the function works on "parameter 7"?

Here is my function:

```
ucl <- 30
lcl <- 25.6

ruleoneviolation <- function(values,ucl,lcl){
    #values <- data %>% pull(col) %>% na.omit()
    len <- length(values) 
    We1 <- c()
    for (i in 1:len) {
        if(!is.na(lcl)  &&  values[i] < as.numeric(as.character(lcl))) {
            We1[i] <- i
        }
        if(!is.na(ucl)  && values[i] > as.numeric(as.character(ucl))){
            We1[i]  <- i  
        }
    }
    We1 <- as.numeric(We1) %>% na.omit() %>% as.numeric()
    return(We1)
}
```

Ideally, the values that are either above 'ucl' or below 'lcl' should be flagged as "We1", but since the vector starts with NA values it flags the incorrect values. When I omit the NA values entirely, it works, but then the dataframe has uneven # of rows.

Comment: When you say "does not work correctly"... what does that mean exactly? What is the expected output?

Comment: I am hoping that We1 will contain the index of values that are above ucl or below lcl. It is indexing the incorrect values because of the NA at the beginning of the parameter

Answer (score 1):

The Base R which() function will give you the index of values outside your normal range.

```
ucl <- 30
lcl <- 25.6

inData <- c(10, 35, NA, NA, 
29L, 28L, 28L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 27L, 27L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 26L, 27L, 29L)

which(inData < lcl | inData > ucl)

[1] 1 2
```